# Materialize SideNav produces multiple #sidenav-overlay

Tags: materialize

I am using Materialize and the sidenav is creating multiple overlays upon clicking the sidenav.

```
 <div id="sidenav-overlay" style="opacity: 1;" class=""></div>
 <div id="sidenav-overlay" style="opacity: 1;" class=""></div>
 <div id="sidenav-overlay" style="opacity: 1;" class=""></div>
```

I found a fix [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/1865) and replaced the sideNav.js file from [here](https://github.com/V07D/materialize/commit/430c652c4d083a44b476d8621ad15d9805c36d8b). But it still doesn't do any good.

Has anyone been stuck in a similar situation and found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The reason there are multiple overlays appearing behind your SideNav is because materialize's `$('.button-collapse').sideNav()` is being run multiple times on the same element.

A quick fix for this is to remove all previous `click()` events from your element before re-initializing materialize's sideNav, like so:

```
$(".button-collapse").off('click').sideNav({ --yourOptions-- });
```

Note: I am not sure what other functionality the ".sideNav()" call may be adding here, there may be a better/more specific way to remove the previous init.

Answer (score 0):

what language you are programming??
I spent something like with asp.net, the mistake was declaring this:

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
```

In MasterPage and ChildPages. Now declaring only MasterPage and the issue was solved.
hopefully help you in something,
Regards

Comment: I had that declared already in my code but didn't help. I am using Javascript (AngularJS to be precise). From whatever I read, I understand that this is a bug with the framework itself. So I added a hack of my own, 

$('body').click(function(){
    $('div[id^=sidenav-overlay]').remove();
})

This ensures that anytime there is an excess of overlay, and the user clicks anywhere on the page, the overlay is removed from DOM. Not the nest soln, but does the job

Comment: some times this overlay is added whenever we have added this plugin more then once $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); I dont know what we have to do if our requirements is more then one sidenav.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the Materialize Framework on Drupal, make sure you do not accidentally side-load another copy of Materialize / Velocity JS through Grunt or other task managers. That would cause the overlay to stack up like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried when I faced similar issue:

```
#sidenav-overlay{ opacity: 0;}

#sidenav-overlay {background-color: transparent;}
```